# Postgis ST_Contains polygon one table

Tags: sql, polygon, postgis

I have a postgis spatial table with polygons in it, having an id (`gid`) and a geometry column named `way` (which actually stores the polygon boundary). The tablehead looks as follows:

```
|| gid (integer) | way (geometry) ||
```

Every column in this table is representing a polygon. Now I want to take two specific polygons out of this table (select them by the gid) and use `ST_Contains()` to test if one is contained by the other.

What is the SQL Syntax for this?

Comment: Are {polygon1, polygon2} actual *columns* of the polygon_table ? Please add the table definition to your question. The question is not very clear either; you want to check if *two records* have overlapping/intersecting polygons?

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: In short: you want to select two records and compare them.

Comment: Yes. Currently I use ST_Contains(geometry1, geometry2) by giving the geometry data directly into it: ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText(...), ST_GeomFromText(...)). But now I want to select two rows (polygons) of the table and put their geometry column ("way") into ST_Contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT st_contains(a.way, b.way)
FROM yourtable AS a, yourtable AS b
WHERE 
    a.gid = yourfirstid
    AND b.gid = yoursecondid
```

Is that all you wanted to know, or did I misinterpret the question?